sql.Вывести количество дубликатов в справочнике товаров
есть таблица с ценами на товары
CREATE TABLE t_goods_price (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    id_goods integer,
    c_price numeric(10,2)
);

в ней могут быть данные такого вида



id_goods
c_price




1
50


1
40


1
50


2
15


2
10


3
100


3
101


3
102


4
15



Нужно запросом получить количество дубликатов товаров с разными ценами
т.е. по итогу должна получиться таблица с товаром, ценой и количеством дубликатов



id_goods
c_price
count_dbl




1
50
1


1
40
1


2
15
1


2
10
1


3
100
2


3
101
2


3
102
2




Что-то я не понял принципа. Объясните, как из первой таблицы получилась вторая. Не общими словами, а конкретно по каждой строчке второй таблицы - как она получилась, почему именно так.

Учитывая, что вы скорее всего очередной бот и мой ответ никому не нужен, просто дам ссылку https://sql-academy.org/ru/guide/groupping выучите - научитесь, а нет.... ну вы поняли

Например, по товару 1 есть 3 записи с ценой 50, 40, 50. нужно для товара 1 с ценой 40 посчитать сколько товаров с другой ценой, в данном случае 1,  для товара 1 с ценой 40 -  один товар 1 с ценой 50. у товара 3 с ценой 100 есть 2 товара 3 с другими ценами

я не бот.....))

В исходной таблице строки 1 и 3 содержат тот же товар с той же ценой. Описание предполагает, что на выходе будет этот товар с этой ценой и количеством 2. Но мы видим в первой строке вывода количество 1. ПОЧЕМУ? И где вообще вывод для последней строки исходных данных, товар 4 цена 15?

Или задача совсем иная? Для каждого товара и цены посчитать количество уникальных, но не совпадающих с текущей, цен того же товара?

@Akina Да, похоже на последнюю вашу формулировку видимо

да, по товару 4 только 1 запись, считаем, что дубликатов у него нет - не выводим

у товара 1 считаем дубликаты только с уникальными ценами

SELECT DISTINCT 
       id_goods, c_price,
       ( SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT c_price)
         FROM t_goods_price t2
         WHERE t1.id_goods = t2.id_goods
           AND t1.c_price <> t2.c_price ) count_dbl
FROM t_goods_price t1
HAVING count_dbl > 0




id_goods
c_price
count_dbl




1
50.00
1


1
40.00
1


2
15.00
1


2
10.00
1


3
100.00
2


3
101.00
2


3
102.00
2



fiddle
Ну или так
SELECT t1.id_goods, t1.c_price, COUNT(DISTINCT t2.c_price) - 1 count_dbl
FROM t_goods_price t1
JOIN t_goods_price t2 USING (id_goods)
GROUP BY 1, 2
HAVING count_dbl > 0


спасибо, пойду пробовать. таблица большая, хотелось еще чтобы не год это все рассчитывалось)

@nikolka Чтобы быстро считалось нужны будут в таблице индексы на id_goods (такой наверняка есть) и на c_price (что вряд ли, если кто-то раньше не делал на этой таблице аналитику, подобную вашей).

@nikolka Индекс CREATE INDEX idx_name ON t_goods_price (id_goods, c_price); совершенно необходим.  И при большом объёме (и особенно - при большом количестве дубликатов по id_goods) первый вариант очевидно выгоднее. А вот если дубликатов (в понимании исходного вопроса) кот наплакал, то выгоднее может оказаться второй вариант. А ещё первый вариант можно переписать на LATERAL JOIN - скорее всего добудется ещё пара процентов.

Если я правильно понял, то схема решения будет примерно такая:

сначала select id_goods group by id_goods, c_price чтобы "схлопнуть" товары с одинаковой ценой в одну запись
затем из получившегося select id_goods, count(*)-1 as count_dbl group by id_goods - собственно счётчик дублей в вашей формулировке
выкинуть записи где получился 0 в count_dbl (судя по отсутствию товара 4 в результате, такие записи выкидываем)
затем join исходной таблицы с тем, что у нас тут получилось


спасибо, попробую

@nikolka В другом ответе готовые решения, лучше их возьмите тогда )
